# SSH Key Set-up for Class

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm setting up SSH keys for a new class (completely new to this stuff) and when I get to the step that states, "Go to GitHub's SSH key settings. Click New SSH key. When the form pops up, enter a name for your computer in the Title input. In the Key input, paste the SSH key you copied."

I follow the instructions and it tells me, "Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key."

1. I know this isn't good, although I have no idea what it means.
2. How do I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

A Complete Newbie

Comment: I suppose it means that your key needs to start with one of those words. This is not on-topic for SO which deals with programming questions, not basic questions about account management. You may have better luck at [su] or just google "set up public key for github".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an ssh key, two files get created in your .ssh directory named, e.g., id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. What you should paste to github is the contents of the .pub file. The .pub file begins with one of those strings, e.g., "ssh-rsa".